# Hibernate 5 Multitenancy and Transactions

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactions, hibernate-5.x

I am using the multitenancy feature of Hibernate 5 implement Multitenancy in an application that currently is single tenant and uses Hibernate 4. I rely on Spring to ensure that the Transactions are managed.

However in Hibernate 5 adding the @Transactional attribute throws up the error
    `SessionFactory configured for multi-tenancy, but no tenant identifier specified`

Based on answers to similar problem, I have implemented the `CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver` interface to account for the fact that the `getCurrentSession()` method of the `SessionFactory` is being used. I have already implemented the `MultiTenantConnectionProvider` interface as well.

However I am now getting the ClassNotFound exception `org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.TransactionContext`. I understand that this is because this class in not available in the Hibernate 5 package.

What is the proper approach to managing transactions using Spring 4.1.6 and Hibernate 5?

Comment: I have the same problem with Hibernate 5 (`SessionFactory configured for multi-tenancy, but no tenant identifier specified`). Were you able to solve it? BTW I'm getting a 'class not found' for `TransactionContext` only when using Spring's hibernate4 support along with Hibernate5.

Comment: UPD: it did not work with Hibernate 5.2.0. Updated to 5.2.2, seems to be working ok. What a funny thing.